# Get two usernames from the same team

Tags: mysql

Below is the query I am using to get the team information. However, I want also display both usernames assorted with the team. The database is setup using two tables. One contains all of the user information and the other (userLeagues) contains a set of ids, such as userID and teamID.

Example - userLeagues

```
leagueID |  userID  | teamID
1         1      1
1         5      1
1         10     2
2         1      1
2         8      1
```

This is result I am trying to achieve.

```
leagueID |  TeamID |   userID1|  userID1
1         1           1         5
```

This would then be outputed as :

```
leagueID |  TeamID  |   userID1  |  userID1

1         Mad Racing  driver 1    dirver 5
```

This is the code I have so far which gets the team but how do I get both driers and their username associated with the same team?

```
SELECT
  u.username
  ,   t.teamName
  ,   t.teamImage    
  /* File Table */
  ,   f.fileType    
FROM
  userleague ul
  INNER JOIN users u ON u.userID = ul.userID
  LEFT JOIN teams t ON t.teamID = ul.teamID
  LEFT JOIN fileType f ON f.fileID = t.fileID                                           
WHERE leagueID = 1     
GROUP BY ul.teamID
```

Comment: Typically this is done with [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) whereby the names are created as a comma-separated list in _one_ column rather than separated out into _multiple columns_, especially if the number of possible results is unknown.  Then it is the responsibility of your application code and display logic to split up the comma-separated list and do something with it. Is that a suitable situation for you?

Comment: So for example: `SELECT leagueID, TeamId, GROUP_CONCAT(username) FROM userLeagues LEFT JOIN users ON userLeagues.userID = users.userID WHERE leagueID = 1 GROUP BY leagueID, TeamId`

Comment: Yea that solution would work, however, how do I then split it up ?

Comment: Michael is right - you don't want to have an arbitrary number of columns in your result set. PHP example: `$array_of_usernames = explode(',', $db_result['grouped_usernames']);`

Comment: That depends on your application code. Are you using something like PHP (`explode(',', $value)`)? SQL alone isn't particularly well-suited to operations that result in a dynamic number of columns....

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic of group-concatenating data only to explode it again immediately after !?!

Comment: @Strawberry The alternative is crazy SQL logic or dynamic SQL to produce a possibly variable number of columns.

Comment: How would then print one driver out into the following line of php? echo "<td><h5 align=\"center\">" . $array_of_usernames['1']  . "</h5></td>\n";

Comment: @user3393730 The first driver would be `$arra_of_usernames[0]`.  The second `$array_of_usernames[1]`.  List them all in a loop: `foreach ($array_of_usernames as $driver) { echo $driver; }`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Surely the alternative is to return a large number of rows, which the application code receives as an array!

Comment: @user3393730 Just remove your GROUP BY clause (and add an ORDER BY clause). Then handle the display logic at the application layer (i.e. a simple PHP loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `min()` and `max()`, if there are only two values:

```
SELECT t.teamName, t.teamImage, f.fileType,
       min(u.username) as user1,
       (case when max(u.username) > min(u.username) then max(u.username) end) as user2   
FROM userleague ul INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON u.userID = ul.userID LEFT JOIN
     teams t
     ON t.teamID = ul.teamID LEFT JOIN
     fileType f
     ON f.fileID = t.fileID                                           
WHERE leagueID = 1     
GROUP BY t.teamName, t.teamImage, f.fileType;
```